# Node JS Use Cheerio to scrape a youtube video

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

*I am trying to develop a system with node.js that updates the video title with the number of views every 60 seconds*. Now, I'm trying to get the number of views and then I'll do the rest. I'm having trouble with the Cheerio API. I then take the response with the page source like this:

```
console.log("Strumento avviato!")


//TODO: get views number with scraping

const urlV = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const axios = require("axios").default;
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: urlV
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        let $ = cheerio.load(body);
        let views = $('.view-count style-scope ytd-video-view-count-renderer');
        console.log(views.text());
    
    })
```

The tag that contains the number of views is the following:

[image]

The problem is that by doing this, return null:

```
let $ = cheerio.load(body);
    let views = $('.view-count style-scope ytd-video-view-count-renderer');
    console.log(views.text());
```

Two blank lines as console output:
[image]

**How could I then extract the number of views?**

Comment: It's generated by JavaScript, you'll need something like puppeteer that runs JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't crawl the DOM to get the view count. You can use the Youtube API to grab the statistics and just parse the json it returns.

I've tested the following, which works:

```
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  json: true,
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos',
  headers: {
    'Referer': 'YOUR DOMAIN URL'
  },
  qs: {
    part: 'statistics',
    id: 'dQw4w9WgXcQ',
    key: 'YOUR API KEY'
  }
};
request(options, function(err, res, body){
  console.log(body.items[0].statistics.viewCount);
});
```

You can get an API key for the Youtube API by following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application). You can set the Referer domain to e.g. http://localhost if you're running this instance locally or whatever domain you control. Just replace YOUR DOMAIN URL with http://localhost or whatever and YOUR API KEY with the API key Google gives you.

Comment: Dude, you just rick-rolled me with that video id XD

Comment: Sorry, it was the first YouTube video that came to mind.

Comment: Don't worry, I appreciated the joke :)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

As [John Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15845138/john-morton) suggested, use official API if you can. However, if you don't want to use it, then you can't get video data from YouTube with Cheerio, because YouTube dynamically loads content on the page via JavaScript.

To get the data you want, you need to use some browser automation, for example [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/). In the code below I show you how you can do this (also check [it on the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Scrape-YouTube-video-page-views-with-NodeJS#index.js)):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const videoLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fou37kNbsqE"; // link to video page

async function getYoutubeVideoPageViews() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);
  await page.goto(videoLink);
  await page.waitForSelector("#contents");
  const isDesign1 = await page.$("#title > h1");
  const views = await page.evaluate((isDesign1) => {
    return parseInt(
      document
        .querySelector(isDesign1 ? "#description-inline-expander > yt-formatted-string span:nth-child(1)" : "#info-text #count")
        ?.textContent.trim()
    );
  }, isDesign1);
  await browser.close();
  return views;
}

getYoutubeVideoPageViews().then(console.log);
```

You can read more about scraping YouTube video page from my blog post [Web scraping YouTube video page with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-video-page-with-nodejs/).